# How to point to one directory up (../) in PHP?

Tags: php

When I'm on this file: `/here/here.php` I can require files from the same folder doing:

```
require_once(__DIR__."/here2.php");
```

However I can't figure out how to go up one directory to point to something such as this:

```
/there/there.php
```

How can I point to this other file with a relative path?

Comment: `/../` to traverse directory up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../there/there.php';
```

or

```
require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/there/there.php';
```